# Hadoop HBase nonstop Memstore flushing "MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush because K has an old edit so flush to free WALs"

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Hello and thanks for reading

I have memstore flush logs for all tables and its non stop

what should I do to identify the reason behind this issue

```
MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush of xyz because K has an old edit so flush to free WALs after random delay 65889ms

2022-10-29 12:22:13,176 INFO  [regionserver/wroker:16020.Chore.1] regionserver.HRegionServer: MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush of 1. because K has an old edit so flush to free WALs after random delay 65889ms
2022-10-29 12:22:13,177 INFO  [regionserver/wroker:16020.Chore.1] regionserver.HRegionServer: MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush of 2 . because K has an old edit so flush to free WALs after random delay 181952ms
2022-10-29 12:22:13,177 INFO  [regionserver/wroker:16020.Chore.1] regionserver.HRegionServer: MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush of 3 . because K has an old edit so flush to free WALs after random delay 150462ms
2022-10-29 12:22:13,177 INFO  [regionserver/wroker:16020.Chore.1] regionserver.HRegionServer: MemstoreFlusherChore requesting flush of 4 . because K has an old edit so flush to free WALs after random delay 161958ms
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean the memstores are *literally* flushing non stop? Or just too frequent?

Comment: thank you for your question 
I took 1 region sample and its flushing every 10 seconds, same for all other regions

Comment: regionserver.HRegion: Flushing 1/1 column families, dataSize=3.90 MB heapSize=11.44 MB